# Word suppress margins error

Tags: vba, ms-word, margins

When printing a Word (2010) document I get the infamous error

> Margins Outside Printable Area

I found out that you can suppress this warning with the following Macro:

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim bPrintBackgroud As Boolean

    'Save current setting of background printing
    bPrintBackgroud = Options.PrintBackground
    Options.PrintBackground = False

    'Turn off DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show

    'Turn on DisplayAlerts again
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

    'Set original background printing setting
    Options.PrintBackground = bPrintBackgroud


End Sub
```

This works, but after the print job is done I still get the margins error. So the script doesn't really suppress the warning, it just delays it. Anyone can point me in the right direction to permanently disable this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

a) remove the problem, which means put your margins within printable area.

b) permanently set `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` which is absolutely NOT recommended. In your situation it means to comment that line:

```
'Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
```

However, if you do so, remember to run the above code when you leave or close document with which you have margin problems. In other situation you won't be informed about problems which you get used to be informed about.

Comment: The margin error started occuring when we updated the firmware of the printer, this was needed because of a maintenance issue. There are a few hundred Word documents that have this error, so resetting the margins on every one of them isn't really an option because this also screws the layout a bit.

Unfortunately, commenting out that line did not work. Still get the error.

Comment: ok, I get your point, made some test with your macro, checked for some solutions and the only idea I have is described in this [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/9730e57c-049a-4490-90be-ac7e31621fa0/) and [here is possible solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259971)

Comment: But this is not let to print to file