# How do I suppress/turn off a particular warning in MS Word using Macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word, suppress-warnings

I am making a brochure for my event in MS Word, and I keep getting this error (when I try to print it) which is really annoying me -

[image]

I found out that one can turn off/suppress warnings using Macros in word. Is there any way I could do the same for this particular warning only? If yes, how should I do it? Kindly guide. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word suppress margins error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782899/word-suppress-margins-error)

Answer (score 0):

Activate the `Developer` tab and use this `VBA` code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open() 'Choose the appropriate event as needed.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Function causing the alert goes here.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this will apply to other alerts as well and that you cannot force any other user to allow macros to run. I agree that this warning is a real pain when nothing is really going to be cut off.